# EventSubscriber called on specific node type or path

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm trying to set an event that will launch function that loads some data from outside server and print it to javascript div element. I tried many ways but I can't figure out how to make this event be **called only on for a specific node type**.

Code I got so far:

```
class eSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::RESPONSE][] = ['onRespond',27]; //so far it works on respond but on every page
    return $events;
  }

  public function onRespond(FilterResponseEvent $event) {
    //do some stuff
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it but I feel it could be done much better.

```
class eSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {

  public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
    $events[KernelEvents::TERMINATE][] = ['onRespond',27];
    return $events;
  }

  public function onRespond(PostResponseEvent $event) {
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    $user = \Drupal::currentUser();
    $name = $user->getUsername();

    $output = [];
    if (isset($node) && isset($name)) {

      $nodeType = $node->getType();
      $soap_response = new classThatHandleRequests();
      $output = $soap_response -> get_clients_fv($name);
      echo('<script>var JSONarray = ' . print_r($output,1) . ';</script>');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `\Drupal` calls should be avoided in classes, use dependency injection instead.