# Limit entity type/bundle for EventSubscriber inside services.yml?

Tags: event-subscribers

I've got an EventSubscriber that I'd like to run for only a specific content type. Is there a way to do this from the services.yml file as an argument or something, or do I just need to check for the entity type in my `OnResponse` method?

Comment: I do think you have to just check in your subscriber. Also, note this related issue: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/240159/eventsubscriber-called-on-specific-node-type-or-path?rq=1

Comment: Hmm, alright. And yes I've got essentially the same solution as that related issue.